# Troubleshooting errors when reading to have not values in the firebase from the flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

When reading the values of Firestore from Flutter, an error occurs if field A is not present.

To solve this problem

```
final A = documentSnapshot['A'] ?? 'No Value'
```

Even if you code with `??`, you will get an error, not a No Value in Text.

How can I solve this?

I looked at a lot of Googling and Flutter books to solve this, but I couldn't find a way.

Comment: whats the datatype of documentsnapshot. Also you might have to access data form dataSnapShot.data

Comment: Field does not exist in Firebase

Comment: sorry? can you try to elaborate

Comment: I do FirebaseFirerestore.instance.collection('users').snapshot() and some of the collection values of users have the field A and some don't.
Fields that are not present at this time are making errors.
How should I handle this error?

Comment: Edit your question with examples. Print out the ones that have A value available and also the ones that don't.

Comment: "errors" is not very descriptive.  Please provide the exact error message and if appropriate the associated stack trace.